Most efficient way to keep track of the samples I already selected from an array
I have a moderately large np array (which could however get larger in the future):
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100_000).reshape((10_000,10))

I need to iteratively choose a random sample (row), making sure that I never choose the same sample twice. Currently I'm doing
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
indices = list(range(len(x)))
for _ in range(1000):
    i = rng.choice(indices)
    ## do something with x[i]
    indices.remove(i)

However, I read that remove is pretty slow. Is there a better way to keep track of the indices I already used?

Just use rng.choice and generate the indices in advance (sample from range 0, N-1 without replacement), then iterate through them.
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
idxs = rng.choice(range(len(x)), size=1000, replace=False)
for i in idxs:
    # do something with x[i]


To get the effect of the OP's original code, I expect you want to pass size=1000 instead.

A flexible way to do this kind of thing is to take your explicit list of indices, and use your library's shuffle() function to scramble it (random.shuffle(indices) in plain Python, but I don't recall exactly how to spell it using numpy's random).
Then your loop becomes:
for _ in range(1000):
    i = indices.pop()
    ## do something with x[i]

I say "flexible" because it isn't confined to a single loop. indices always contains the collection of indices not yet visited. So it can be reused by more loops, if wanted, or even passed to functions.
Or, e.g., if at some point you want a chunk of k fresh indices instead,
    ichunk = indices[-k:]
    del indices[-k:]

Using pop() is important to speed: removing from the end of a list is cheap. In effect, Python just decrements an internal pointer to where the list ends. Similarly for del[-k:]. In general, remove() has to physically move every element to the right of the removed element left by a position, to "fill the hole". That takes average-case time proportional to the length of the list. But when removing from the end, there is no hole to fill.

One option might be to keep a list of pointers (indexes) into the array, originally in order, that you don’t require to be in any particular order to sample and that you can swap and pop efficiently:
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
indices = np.arange(len(x))
indices_left = len(x)
for _ in range(1000):
    i = rng.integers(indices_left)
    ## do something with x[indices[i]]
    indices[i] = indices[indices_left - 1]  # swap
    indices_left -= 1  # pop

